# What are the Team City best practices for multistage deployment?

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, teamcity

We have 3 environments:

- **Development:** Team City deploys here for Subversion commits on trunk.
- **Staging:** User acceptance is done here, on builds that are release candidates.
- **Production:** When UAT passed, the passing code set is deployed here.

We're using Team City and only have Continuous Integration setup with our development environment. I don't want to save artifacts for every development deployment that Team City does. I want an assigned person to be able to fire a build configuration that will deploy a certain successful development deployment to our staging server.

Then, I want each staging deployment to save artifacts. When a staging deployment passes UAT, I want to deploy that package to Production.

I'm not sure how to set this up in Team City. I'm using version 6.5.4, and I'm aware there's a "Promote..." action/trigger, but I think it depends on saved artifacts. I don't want to save development deployments each time as artifacts, but I do want the person running the staging deployment to be able to specify which successful development deployment to deploy to staging.

I'm aware there may be multiple ways to do this, is there a best practice? What is your setup and why do you recommend it?

**Update:**

I have one answer so far, and it's an idea we had considered internally. I'd really like to know if anyone has a somewhat automated way for deploying to a staging/production environemnt via Team City itself, where only people with certain role/permission can run a deploy script to production rather than having to manually deal with any kind of artifact package. Anyone?

**Update 2**

I still have 1 day to award bounty, and I thought the answer below didn't answer my question, but after rereading it I see that my question wasn't what I thought it was.

Are there any ways to use Team City for some kind of automated deployment to Staging/Production environments?

Comment: A bit late here but, seems like you’d really benefit from a defined [DevOps toolchain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps_toolchain) and most definitely an application release automation tool. This is becoming the standard – using tools like TeamCity of CI and linking into ARA tools for coordination and deployments. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_release_automation

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you're actually asking two different questions here; one is about controlling access rights to TeamCity builds and another is about the logistics of artifact management.

---

Regarding permissions, I assume what you mean by "only people with certain role/permission can run a deploy script to production" and your response to Julien is that you probably don't want devs deploying direct to production but you *do* want them to be able to see other builds in the project. This is possibly also similar to Julien's scenario when IT then take the process "offline" from TeamCity (either that or it's just IT doing what IT do and insisting they must use a separate, entirely inefficient process because "that's just the way we do it" - don't get me started on that!)

The problem is simply that all permissions in TeamCity are applied against the *project* and never the *build* so if you've got one project with all your builds, there's no ability to apply permissions granularity to dev versus production builds. I've previously dealt with this in two ways:

1. Handle it socially. Everyone knows what their responsibilities are and you don't run what you're not meant to run. If you do, it's audited and traceable back to YOU. Work fine when there's maturity, a clear idea of responsibilities and not compliance requirement that prohibits it.
2. Create separate projects. I don't like having to do this but it *does* fix the problem. You can still use artifacts from another project and means you simply end up with one project containing builds that deploy to environments you're happy for all the devs to access and another project to sensitive environments. The downside is that if the production build fails, the very people you probably want support from won't be able to access it!

---

Regarding artifact management, there's no problem with retaining these in the development build, just define a clean-up policy that only keeps artifacts from the last X builds if you're worried about capacity. A lot of people want certainty they're deploying the same compiled output to every environment which means once you build it, you want to keep it around for later use.

Once you have these artefacts from your dev deployment, you can re-deploy them to your other environments through separate builds. You'll have an issue with config transforms (assuming you're using them), but have a read of [this 2 part series](http://blog.blueline-coding.co.uk/?p=17) for some ideas on how to address that (I'm yet to absorb it in detail but I believe he's on the right track).

Does that answer your question? Is there anything still missing?

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. I'm very clear on permissions now. I'll have to read that 2 part series you linked to regarding the config transforms. Unfortunately, we have very few .NET 4.0 projects currently. Most of our apps are 2.0 framework, and we're relying on the very flimsy and lucky "Don't copy over web.config" to manage config files. Hence, I just have a simple NAnt (because it seems easier than MSBuild to me) scripts to delete old files and copy over with new ones, excluding web.config.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can still keep your projects in .NET 2 *and* use config transforms, you just need to have Visual Studio 2010. That might be your best middle ground.

Comment: Interesting...We have them running in a 2010 solution now, but for some reason I couldn't figure out how to get the config transformations working. I thought it was because it's running in 2.0 Framework, not 4.0.

Comment: In VS2010, just right-click on your web.config and choose "Add Config Transforms". This feature is independent of the .NET version.

Comment: Okay, so my problem was that this project is a Web Site project, not Web App. Apparently config transformations won't work there, which isn't surprising.

Comment: You're link to dealing with config transforms is dead.

Answer (score 8):

We also used TeamCity as our build server so let me explain our setup. 
We have 4 environments

- Development used by Dev to verify commits in a server environment
- QA for testing purposes
- Staging for deployment checks and some UAT
- Production

We only use TeamCity to deploy to Development (Nightly builds) and to QA (on-demand).
The Dev build uses the trunk branch and QA build uses a different branch used for the RC.

Deployment to the Staging and Production are managed by the IT team, and are therefore not automated.

What we do instead is that we use TeamCity to produce artifacts from the QA build. The artifacts are the deployment kits sent for Staging/Production deployments.

That said, I am not sure if TeamCity would provide you a complete control on which build can be promoted to which environment. We basically control this on the SVN side with branches, and have different builds for those branches. You could (should) do be able to manage this it the same way. You can therefore ensure what is getting deployed.

I understand that your needs may be slightly different than ours but I hope that this will helps you finding the best setup.

Comment: My colleague and I were discussing using a QA branch, and then it would make sense to handle staging/production deployments with artifacts. I'd still really like to be able to give only a certain set of people permissions to run a build for the production deployment, that way we have a nice history of production deployments as a log inside of Team City. The thought of all the merging in Subversion is already giving me headaches! :) We're trying to move to DVCS...that would make this sort of setup much easier.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might want to check out something like [Octopus Deploy](http://octopusdeploy.com/) or [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster/overview). They provide a nice structure for the deployment practices you're trying to automate. Both tools integrate with TeamCity nicely.

Basically, you'd continue to use TeamCity for CI, and you could also continue to deploy to your development environment with TeamCity too, but you'd use one of the deployment tools to promote an (existing) build to staging and production.

*Edit 2014-02-05 – Update*

The makers of BuildMaster have a new deployment feature – [ProGet Deploy](http://inedo.com/support/tutorials/a-gentle-introduction-to-proget-deploy) – for their NuGet server tool, [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget/overview). It's very similar to Octopus Deploy, tho I haven't played with it yet myself, so Octopus may have a better visualization of what versions have been deployed to which environments; I still use BuildMaster because of that important feature.

Also, I'm currently using both TeamCity, BuildMaster, and ProGet and I never want to go back to not having automated builds. Currently, all of my apps are built and deployed via BuildMaster. All of my library projects are built in TeamCity and deployed to ProGet. Being able to manage my internal dependencies via the NuGet infrastructure is *nice*.